# DomContentLoaded Triggering Extremely Fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking at www.quicksprout.com/blog/ and I haven't been able to figure out how DomContentLoaded is triggering after just a few files are loaded instead of waiting for all the images and everything else.
If you look at it with WebPageTest you can see that it will trigger after 500ms to 750ms, way before the rest of the page is loaded.

I looked at javascript and HTML but I don't see how they've managed to optimize their site to that degree. Is the browser somehow interpreting the DOM completely?

[Edit] Some here are arguing that the DOM doesn't wait for Javascript or anything else. Great. Then what causes the rendering to actually start? What does block the DOM? Because clearly heavier pages render later.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, **without waiting for stylesheets, images,**
>   **and subframes to finish loading**

In other words, as soon as the DOM is ready, i.e. elements are available, the event fires, it does not wait for files, images etc. to load, that would be `window.onload`

Comment: I understand but if you see that page's source code, they have css and js at the top. The DOMContentLoaded triggers way before a lot of that is even downloaded. I guess what I'm asking is what would delay the DOM from being ready.

Comment: @JOAXLE again: DomContentLoaded doesnt wait for ANY download to be finished EXCEPT the html-document itself

Comment: @Fuzzyma - From what you're saying, once HTML is received rendering should be immediate. From experience I know this is not the case as rendering could take several seconds on other websites, much later than HTML is received. I am looking for an example to provide.

Comment: Rendering includes loading and displaying images. That has nothing to do with the DomContentLoaded-Event

Comment: @JOAXLE - first of all, that site uses Wordpress, which is somewhat optimized for loading times. Secondly, it uses a CDN to load all the scripts, which is probably very fast. Thirdly, as noted above, DOMContentLoaded doesn't wait for resources to load, only the HTML itself to ensure elements are available.

Comment: @Fuzzyma - Take a look http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150123_1T_138Z/1/details/

Here you can clearly see that the site completes the dom and begins rendering very quickly, and images that are not in view are loaded later it seems.

Comment: @JOAXLE - and again, DOMContentLoaded **does not** wait for images to load

Comment: @adeneo - Wordpress can be good or it can suck. Wordpress itself isn't optimized for anything. The CDN makes it faster to load the scripts, that's true, but there are many more scripts that take longer to load and the browser doesn't wait for them. The question is why the rendering doesn't wait. What is designed in the structure to make it render so quickly with only a small set of elements.

Comment: I think Wordpress generally sucks, but the devs at Automaticc have been optimizing the markup it spits out for the last ten years, so it's pretty darn efficient, the reason it can be slow is DB lookups, which are horrible in Wordpress.

Comment: @adeneo - Would waiting for fonts be a reason for rendering to be delayed?
I see this page loads the fonts at the top and then after these are in the rendering begins. Whereas other pages the fonts get loaded at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by fast rendering, but DOMContentLoaded and rendering are two different things, and the site you're linking to is nothing special, without cache it takes about 1.5 seconds to load, and it seems to have cache settings set correctly and generally small images and files, but it's nothing special. If your page takes 4 seconds to load, you probably have an issue somewhere, and you should try testing it, for instance with PageSpeed or GTMetrix

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind DomContentLoaded is, to have an event which fires when the full Dom is loaded (the html-structure).

A t this point every Javascript-command accessing elements wont fail anymore. You dont need the images to do something with an img-tag for example.

If you wanna wait until the full page is completely loaded use `onload` instead.

Comment: Fuzzyma - I have my own website which takes about 3-5 seconds before DomContentLoaded is triggered. What I'm trying to do is what these guys did to be able to get the rendering to show up immediately, so people see web page loading fast.

Comment: Please specify your question then